# C# Non-Integer enums and Casting

Tags: c#, casting, enums, xna

C# allows you to assign values to your enum elements such as

```
public enum Animals
{
    Dog = 0, Cat = 1,
}
```

And You can cast too and from them like so.

```
public void demo()
{
    int dog = (int)Animals.Dog;
    Animals cat = (Animals)(dog++);
}
```

But c# also lets you do things like this

```
public enum Animals
{
    Dog = Vector2.One, Cat = Vector2.Zero,
}
```

However you cannot get the Vector2 back in and out with a cast. such as

```
Vector2 dog = (Vector2)Animals.Dog; //this fails
```

Is this problem solvable? *Note `Vector2` is a class object and `Vector2.One` and `Vector2.Zero` are static declarations of such. Which means Dog is assigned to a memory reference.

Comment: This code won't compile - `Vector2` has to be convertible to int (or if you specify any of the other allowed base types of enum which are only integral types)

Comment: Vector2 is not a class, it's a structure and a value type (assuming your are using the XNA Vector2 and not your own implementation).

Comment: @BrokenGlass Hmm, my Kreskin hat (http://www.amazingkreskin.com/) is out at the cleaners too! ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way that C# will let you do

```
public enum Animals
{
    Dog = Vector2.One,
    Cat = Vector2.Zero
}
```

Is if there is an implicit cast from `Vector2` to an integral type.  Otherwise, you will get a compile error.  This is why you cannot cast back to `Vector2` - there is no cast from `int` back to `Vector2`.  `Dog` and `Cat` are integer valued, and the values come from the implicit cast from `Vector2.One` and `Vector2.Zero` to `int`, respectively.

You could define your own explicit cast to make it work, but I'm guessing you won't be able to get back all the information you want that way.

Comment: This is true. It passed the pre-compiler, not the compiler. This makes more sense now.